# contact form submit button works on desktop but NOT on mobile

Tags: html, forms, contact-form

Hi Guys please assist,

I have an HTML form the submit button works on desktop but not on mobile any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<form id="contact" action="mailto:Enquiry@commoditymovers.co.za" method="post">
<h3>Complete the below form!</h3>
<fieldset>
<input placeholder="Your name" type="name" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input placeholder="What are you inquiring?" type="subject" tabindex="4" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<textarea placeholder="Give us more details..." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: "*Works*" in this context is a very subjective term. Edit your question to be more specific about *how* it works or doesn't work. What happens? Is there any error message? Does the message show up or not?

Comment: http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html

Comment: Thank you @esqew, when I fill in the form and click on submit nothing happens no pop up to select which mail to use nothing happen upon clicking submit to send the mail. But when no field has been entered and i click submit it says field must be entered